# Folder/Directory upload to python (flask) built website

Tags: python, flask, directory-structure

I am relatively new to web development and have been experimenting with the flask module in python. I am working on a project that analyzes social media metadata. For ease of use I am trying to establish a way for the user to upload a folder of their metadata to an online link, and then temporarily save that data and perform a series of functions to represent said data. Any direction would be greatly appreciated

I used the flask function get_file() but can only upload 1 file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.